# ObjC2J not working

Tags: java, android, ios, converters, objc2j

I am trying to use this tool, ObjC2J, but it keeps asking for me to put the "converter.properties" file in the MacOSX.sdk file. I am copying the converter.properties file from the file that consists of the tool to

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

This was the only appropriate place I saw for this file as this is where the sdk resides and the path of the txt file is similar to my path yet i still get the "You should create 'converter.properties' file and place there path to MacOSX.sdk" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess, I can help you, because `ObjC2j` is my creation. Where did you place `converter.properties`?